# RuntimeError: Binary 'sox' could not be found

Tags: python, windows, speech-recognition, sox

I am playing with google speech library as follows:

```
from google_speech import Speech

# say "Hello World"
text = "Hello World"
lang = "en"
speech = Speech(text, lang)
speech.play()
```

getting this error:

```
RuntimeError                          

    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-4daa3294f636> in <module>()
----> 1 from google_speech import Speech
      2 
      3 # say "Hello World"
      4 text = "Hello World"
      5 lang = "en"

D:\soft\Ins\anac\lib\site-packages\google_speech\__init__.py in <module>()
    321 
    322 # check deps
--> 323 bin_dep.check_bin_dependency(("sox",))
    324 
    325 

D:\soft\Ins\anac\lib\site-packages\google_speech\bin_dep.py in check_bin_dependency(bins)
      5   for bin in bins:
      6     if shutil.which(bin) is None:
----> 7       raise RuntimeError("Binary '%s' could not be found" % (bin))

RuntimeError: Binary 'sox' could not be found
```

i am working on windows, and i did all instructions:

If you don't already have it, install pip for Python 3
Install Google Speech: `pip3 install google_speech`
Install SoX, with MP3 support. On Ubuntu and other Debian derivatives: `sudo apt-get install sox libsox-fmt-mp3`. Windows users can download binaries on the SoX website, once installed you also need to copy libmad DLL in the directory where you have installed SoX, and to add this directory to your PATH environment variable.

Comment: a reset solved the problem!

Answer (score 5):

You can find binaries and installers for SoX on its sourceforge downloads page:
    [Get it from here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sox/files/sox/)

Adding SoX to your path

First, find the directory where SoX is installed. By default, this is probably C:\Program Files (x86)\sox-14-4-1 or C:\Program Files\sox-14-4-1

This directory needs to be added to your PATH environment variable. Open a command prompt by pressing the Windows key and typing cmd.exe (on Vista or later), or by choosing "Run" from the Start Menu and type cmd (on earlier versions).

Type path into the command prompt and it should return your PATH variable (PATH= followed by a list of directories). To temporarily add SoX to your PATH variable, type the following command (replace the C:\Program Files (x86)\sox-14-4-1 with your SoX directory if necessary):

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\sox-14-4-1
```

Type path again, and it should return the same list of directories as before, but with the string ;C:\Program Files (x86)\sox-14-4-1 added to the very end. If it returns anything else (e.g., if it only returns the SoX directory), don't proceed to the next step (close the command prompt window and start over). If it returns the same list plus SoX, you can add SoX permanently by using the setx command instead of set:

```
setx PATH %PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\sox-14-4-1
```

On Windows XP, you'll need to install the Windows XP SP2 Support Tools before you can do this.
Checking for success

To check that this worked, open a new command prompt and type sox. If this is successful, it will return information on using SoX, but otherwise it should return "sox is not recognized".